# Jenkins not responding

Tags: url, jenkins, amazon-ec2, service

I have newly installed Jenkins on my Amazon-AWS server. I changed the Jenkins port to 8081 and started it. I verified that the Jenkins is running on port `8081`.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-247 ~]$ ps -eaf | grep 8081
jenkins   1370     1  0 03:42 ?        00:00:11 /etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=8081 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
ec2-user  1611  1585  0 04:34 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 8081
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-247 ~]$
```

However when I try to access the Jenkins using this url:
http://ec2-54-214-126-0.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8081

it says that

> This site can’t be reached ec2-54-214-126-0.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com took too long to respond.

On the same server I am running tomcat on port: `8080` which I can access and it shows the tomcat homepage.

http://ec2-54-214-126-0.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/

I am new to Jenkins.

Comment: StackOverflow if for questions about software programming. Your questions is about server administration, you may ask it on ServerFault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the guide "[Set Up a Jenkins Build Server -- Quickly create a build server for continuous integration (CI) on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/setup-jenkins-build-server/)"

It does has a section about a security group for the Amazon EC2 instance, which acts as a
firewall that controls the traffic allowed to reach one or more EC2 instances.

Maybe 8081 is not part of that security group.

Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
In the left-hand navigation bar, choose Security Groups.
Click `Add Rule`, and then choose `Custom TCP Rule` from the `Type` list.
Under Port Range enter 8081.

Comment: Hi VonC, Thank you I forgot to respond. Your solution worked for me.